# Comparing two double value but result are strange

Tags: c++, compare, double

I want to compare *double* value, but results are out of my intention. (my intention is to go to `for` loop, but the result is to go to `else if`) I don't understand why this result are occurred, Does anyone know why this result occurred?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int count=0;

double money_arr[11]={100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05};


bool double_compare(double a, double b)
{
    return fabs(a-b)<0.0001?true:false;
}

void case_num(double n, double sum)
{
    double tmp = (double)sum-n;
    printf("n: %lf sum :%lf",n, sum);
    if(double_compare(n,sum))
    {
        count++;

        return;
    }

    else if(tmp>0.0);
    {
        cout<<"DSsfdsd";
        return ;
    }

    for(int i=10; i>=0; i++)
    {
        cout<<i<<endl;
        if(n-sum>money_arr[i])
        case_num(n, sum+money_arr[i]);

    }
}

int main()
{
    double n;

    if((double)0.20>(double)0.1)
        cout<"esdfkjsldf";

    cin>>n;

    //cout<<n;
    case_num(n,0);

    //cout<<count<<endl;
}
```

Comment: If you are counting monye, it's ALWAYS better to count in integer values because floating point is not precise - multiply your starting value up by 100 and use that as an integer value (or even better, read it in as a string, and convert directly to integer). Whilst there are other things wrong in your code, this will help you in the future. There is nothing worse than typing in "Pay $17.10" and the machine says "You have not paid the full amount, there is $0.00 left to pay" (but you haven't got any 0.0000001 coins that you can pay ins, so it's never going to happen)

Answer (score 2):

```
else if(tmp>0.0);
```

Get rid of that semi-colon which is ending the `if` statement early.